# How to get Contact ID, Email, Phone number in one SQLite query ? Contacts Android Optimization

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to fetch All Contacts atleast with one phone Number, also I want all Phone Numbers and All emails for every Contact.

Current code :

```
// To get All Contacts having atleast one phone number.

Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " > ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"0"};
Cursor cu = applicationContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, 
                null, selection, selectionArgs, null);

// For getting All Phone Numbers and Emails further queries : 
while(cu.moveToNext()){
String id = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));


 // To get Phone Numbers of Contact
    Cursor pCur = context.getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,  null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
 new String[]{id}, null);

// To get Email ids of Contact
Cursor emailCur = context.getContentResolver().query(
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
new String[]{id}, null); 

// Iterate through these cursors to get Phone numbers and Emails
}
```

If there are more than 1000 contacts in my Device, it is taking too much time. How can I get All Data in single query, rather than doing two additional queries for each contact?

Or is there any other way to optimize?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: while starting your app,process this code for first time and save all  that data means,email,phoennumber in static arraylist and from that you can get each data as per you want

Comment: @jenuine : I am doing that, this code comes in to picture when there is some change in Contacts, like new contact added, deleted, modified.

Comment: yeah.thats an issue,but i didnt used,the contentobserver in android,but am sure  this issue can be solved..

Answer (score 50, accepted):

ICS: When you query from `Data.CONTENT_URI` you have all the rows from the associated `Contact` already joined - i.e. this would work:

**Java:**

```
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = resolver.query(
            Data.CONTENT_URI, 
            null, 
            Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "!=0 AND (" + Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?)", 
            new String[]{Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},
            Data.CONTACT_ID);
    
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(Data.CONTACT_ID));
        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String data1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Data.DATA1));
        
        System.out.println(id + ", name=" + name + ", data1=" + data1);
    }
```

**Kotlin:**

```
        var c : Cursor? = null
        try {
                val resolver : ContentResolver = this.contentResolver //Replace "this" With Whatever The Reference To Your Activity Is (If Need Be)
                c = resolver.query(
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "!=0 AND (" + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?)",
                    arrayOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE),
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID)

                if (c!!.count > 0) {
                    while (c.moveToNext()) {
                        val id : Long = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID))
                        val name : String = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME))
                        val data1 : String = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1))

                        Log.d("Tag", "$id) name=$name, data1=$data1")
                    }
                }
        } finally {
            c?.close() //<-- close if not null
        }
```

If you are targeting 2.3 you need to account for the fact that `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` is not available through the joins used when querying `Data`.

*Fun*.

This could, for instance,  be solved either by skipping your requirement that the contact *must* have a phone number and instead settle for "any contact with at least a phone number or an e-mail address":

```
Cursor c = resolver.query(
        Data.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, 
        Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", 
        new String[]{Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},
        Data.CONTACT_ID);
```

If that is not an option you can always go for a horribly **hacky** sub-select:

```
Cursor c = resolver.query(
        Data.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, 
        "(" + Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?) AND " + 
        Data.CONTACT_ID + " IN (SELECT " + Contacts._ID + " FROM contacts WHERE " + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "!=0)", 
        new String[]{Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}, Data.CONTACT_ID);
```

or solve it by using **two** `Cursor`s:

```
Cursor contacts = resolver.query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
        null, Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " != 0", null, Contacts._ID + " ASC");
Cursor data = resolver.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, null, 
        Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + Data.MIMETYPE + "=?", 
        new String[]{Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}, 
        Data.CONTACT_ID + " ASC");

int idIndex = contacts.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contacts._ID);
int nameIndex = contacts.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
int cidIndex = data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Data.CONTACT_ID);
int data1Index = data.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Data.DATA1);
boolean hasData = data.moveToNext();

while (contacts.moveToNext()) {
    long id = contacts.getLong(idIndex);
    System.out.println("Contact(" + id + "): " + contacts.getString(nameIndex));
    if (hasData) {
        long cid = data.getLong(cidIndex);
        while (cid <= id && hasData) {
            if (cid == id) {
                System.out.println("\t(" + cid + "/" + id + ").data1:" + 
                        data.getString(data1Index));
            }
            hasData = data.moveToNext();
            if (hasData) {
                cid = data.getLong(cidIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This great! However I wonder if I combine the cursor for Phone and Email, how can I differentiate whether the data1 is a phone or email?

Comment: You check if the value of `Data.MIMETYPE` is either `Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE` or `Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE`.

Comment: hi jens. will you please answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699578/how-to-get-contacts-the-first-name-last-name-email-id-from-single-query-in-an @Jens

Comment: hi jens, How can i check whether it is Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE or Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE.

Comment: Thanks It worked for me too but I also need to get phone type. How can I get the phone type.

Comment: You need to retrieve the mimetype like this String mimeType = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE)); and then you can do a if test mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)

Answer (score 5):

I went through the exact same problem. Since then I build my own solution which is inspired from this post yet a bit different. Now I'd like to share it as my first StackOverFlow answer :-)

Its quite similar to the double cursor approach suggested by Jens. The idea is to

1- fetch relevant contact from the Contacts table 
2- fetch relevant Contacts information (mail, phone, ...)
3- combine these results

The "relevant" is up to you of course but the important point is the performance !
Besides, I'm sure other solutions using well suited SQL query might as well do the job but here I only want to use the Android ContentProvider
Here is the code :

### Some constants

```
public static String CONTACT_ID_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
public static String DATA_CONTACT_ID_URI = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID;
public static String MIMETYPE_URI = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE;
public static String EMAIL_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;
public static String PHONE_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA;
public static String NAME_URI = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) ? ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY : ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME;
public static String PICTURE_URI = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) ? ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI : ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID;

public static String MAIL_TYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
public static String PHONE_TYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
```

### 1 Contact

Here I require that the Contacts must have DISPLAY_NAME free of "@" and that their informations match a given string (these requirement can of course be modified). The result of the following method is the first cursor :

```
public Cursor getContactCursor(String stringQuery, String sortOrder) {

    Logger.i(TAG, "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    Logger.e(TAG, "ContactCursor search has started...");

    Long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Uri CONTENT_URI;

    if (stringQuery == null)
        CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    else
        CONTENT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(stringQuery));

    String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
            CONTACT_ID_URI,
            NAME_URI,
            PICTURE_URI
    };

    String SELECTION = NAME_URI + " NOT LIKE ?";
    String[] SELECTION_ARGS = new String[]{"%" + "@" + "%"};

    Cursor cursor = sContext.getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, SELECTION_ARGS, sortOrder);

    Long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Logger.e(TAG, "ContactCursor finished in " + (t1 - t0) / 1000 + " secs");
    Logger.e(TAG, "ContactCursor found " + cursor.getCount() + " contacts");
    Logger.i(TAG, "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

    return cursor;
}
```

This query is quite performant as you'll see !

### 2 Contact Details

Now let's fetch Contact informations. At this point, I dont make any link between the already fetched Contact and the retrieved information : I just fetch all informations form the Data table... Yet, to avoid useless info I still require DISPLAY_NAMES free of "@" and since I'm interested in email and phone I require that the data MIMETYPE to be either MAIL_TYPE or PHONE_TYPE (see Constants). Here is the code :

```
public Cursor getContactDetailsCursor() {

    Logger.i(TAG, "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    Logger.e(TAG, "ContactDetailsCursor search has started...");

    Long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
            DATA_CONTACT_ID_URI,
            MIMETYPE_URI,
            EMAIL_URI,
            PHONE_URI
    };

    String SELECTION = ContactManager.NAME_URI + " NOT LIKE ?" + " AND " + "(" + MIMETYPE_URI + "=? " + " OR " + MIMETYPE_URI + "=? " + ")";

    String[] SELECTION_ARGS = new String[]{"%" + "@" + "%", ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

    Cursor cursor = sContext.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION,
            SELECTION,
            SELECTION_ARGS,
            null);

    Long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Logger.e(TAG, "ContactDetailsCursor finished in " + (t1 - t0) / 1000 + " secs");
    Logger.e(TAG, "ContactDetailsCursor found " + cursor.getCount() + " contacts");
    Logger.i(TAG, "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

    return cursor;
}
```

Once again you will see that this query is quite fast...

### 3 Combining

Now let's combine both Contact and their respective informations. The idea is to use HashMap(Key, String) where Key is the Contact id and String is whatever you like (name, email, ...).

First, I run through the Contact cursor (which is alphabetically ordered) and store names and picture uri in two different HashMap. Note also that I store all Contact id's in a List in the very same order that Contacts appear in the cursor. Lets call this list contactListId

I do the same for the Contact informations (mail and email). But now I take care of the correlation between the two cursor : if the CONTACT_ID of an email or phone does not appear in contactListId it is put aside. I check also if the email has already been encountered. Notice that this further selection can introduce asymmetries between the Name/Picture content and the Email/Phone HashMap content but don't worry.

Eventually, I run over the contactListId list and build a list of Contact object taking care of the fact that : a contact must have information (keySet condition) and that the contact must have at least a mail or an email (the case where mail == null && phone == null may appear if the contact is a Skype contact for instance). 
And here is the code :

```
public List<Contact> getDetailedContactList(String queryString) {

    /**
     * First we fetch the contacts name and picture uri in alphabetical order for
     * display purpose and store these data in HashMap.
     */

    Cursor contactCursor = getContactCursor(queryString, NAME_URI);

    List<Integer> contactIds = new ArrayList<>();

    if (contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            contactIds.add(contactCursor.getInt(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_ID_URI)));
        } while (contactCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    HashMap<Integer, String> nameMap = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Integer, String> pictureMap = new HashMap<>();

    int idIdx = contactCursor.getColumnIndex(CONTACT_ID_URI);

    int nameIdx = contactCursor.getColumnIndex(NAME_URI);
    int pictureIdx = contactCursor.getColumnIndex(PICTURE_URI);

    if (contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            nameMap.put(contactCursor.getInt(idIdx), contactCursor.getString(nameIdx));
            pictureMap.put(contactCursor.getInt(idIdx), contactCursor.getString(pictureIdx));
        } while (contactCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    /**
     * Then we get the remaining contact information. Here email and phone
     */

    Cursor detailsCursor = getContactDetailsCursor();

    HashMap<Integer, String> emailMap = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Integer, String> phoneMap = new HashMap<>();

    idIdx = detailsCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA_CONTACT_ID_URI);
    int mimeIdx = detailsCursor.getColumnIndex(MIMETYPE_URI);
    int mailIdx = detailsCursor.getColumnIndex(EMAIL_URI);
    int phoneIdx = detailsCursor.getColumnIndex(PHONE_URI);

    String mailString;
    String phoneString;

    if (detailsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            /**
             * We forget all details which are not correlated with the contact list
             */

            if (!contactIds.contains(detailsCursor.getInt(idIdx))) {
                continue;
            }

            if(detailsCursor.getString(mimeIdx).equals(MAIL_TYPE)){
                mailString = detailsCursor.getString(mailIdx);

                /**
                 * We remove all double contact having the same email address
                 */

                if(!emailMap.containsValue(mailString.toLowerCase()))
                    emailMap.put(detailsCursor.getInt(idIdx), mailString.toLowerCase());

            } else {
                phoneString = detailsCursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                phoneMap.put(detailsCursor.getInt(idIdx), phoneString);
            }

        } while (detailsCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    contactCursor.close();
    detailsCursor.close();

    /**
     * Finally the contact list is build up
     */

    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    Set<Integer> detailsKeySet = emailMap.keySet();

    for (Integer key : contactIds) {

        if(!detailsKeySet.contains(key) || (emailMap.get(key) == null && phoneMap.get(key) == null))
            continue;

        contacts.add(new Contact(String.valueOf(key), pictureMap.get(key), nameMap.get(key), emailMap.get(key), phoneMap.get(key)));
    }

    return contacts;
}
```

The Contact object definition is up to you.

Hope this will help and thanks for the previous post.

### Correction/Improvement

I forgot to check the phone key set : it should rather looks like

```
!mailKeySet.contains(key)
```

replaced by

```
 (!mailKeySet.contains(key) && !phoneKeySet.contains(key))
```

with the phone keySet

```
Set<Integer> phoneKeySet = phoneMap.keySet();
```

I why not add an empty contact cursor check like :

```
if(contactCursor.getCount() == 0){
        contactCursor.close();
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

right after the getContactCursor call

Comment: In `ContactManager.NAME_URI`, 

`ContactManager` should be removed.